# Limit number input to range

Tags: javascript, jquery, range

I want to limit a user input to a specific range (-90 to 90). Number can be integer or decimal. The default value must be `0`. I do **not** want to use HTML5 `min` / `max` attributes.

This is my HTML:

```
<input type="number" value="0" />
```

This is what I have tried:

```
$('input').on('input', function () {

    var value = $(this).val();
    $(this).val(Math.max(Math.min(value, 90), -90));
});
```

This is buggy because it doesn't let me erase the default value (therefore I cannot enter a `-` for a negative number or a `.` for a decimal number).

So I ended up doing this:

```
$('input').on('input', function () {

    var value = $(this).val();

    if ((value !== '') && (value.indexOf('.') === -1)) {

        $(this).val(Math.max(Math.min(value, 90), -90));
    }
});
```

That's better, but now the problem is that I can enter `90.1` which is out of my defined range.

Suggestions?

<kbd>[JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/upsidown/uw1h6d6c/)</kbd>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider *only* modifying the value when it's out of range. This lets you include decimals, etc.

```js
$('input').on('input', function () {
    
    var value = this.value;
    
    if (value !== '') {
        value = parseFloat(value);
        
        if (value < -90)
            this.value = -90;
        else if (value > 90)
            this.value = 90;
    }
    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="number" value="0" />
```

Comment: If you replace 'if (value < -90)' to be for example 'if (value < 10)' and 'this.value = 10;' instead, it breaks the input field when typing and deleting. How would that be handled?