# Mix/max range applied to specific number input field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors

Using [a solution from a relevant question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26654023/8725816), how can I use the following script to only work on a specific input by limiting the input range between 0 and 0.20? For example, I have two number inputs with the ID's "A" and "B", and I only want the following script to work on input id="A".

```js
$('input').on('input', function () {
    
    var value = this.value;
    
    if (value !== '') {
        value = parseFloat(value);
        
        if (value < 0)
            this.value = 0;
        else if (value > 0.20)
            this.value = 0.20;
    }
    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="number" id="a" value="0" />
<input type="number" id="b" value="0" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the ID of the specific element.

`$('#a').on('input', function () {`

Demo:

```js
$('#a').on('input', function() {

  var value = this.value;

  if (value !== '') {
    value = parseFloat(value);

    if (value < 0)
      this.value = 0;
    else if (value > 0.20)
      this.value = 0.20;
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="number" id="a" value="0" />
<input type="number" id="b" value="0" />
```

Alternatively, if you only need to support HTML5-compatible browsers you could ditch the JavaScript and simply use `min` and `max` attributes on the element itself. You can also use `step` to control how much the button increases the value by, which makes sense in a scenario where the input range is so small:

```html
<input type="number" id="a" value="0" min="0" max="0.2" step="0.1" />
<input type="number" id="b" value="0" />
```

Comment: @JohnGIS No problem. I just updated with an even simpler way to do it. Also, it may be worth reading https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/ to learn about all the selectors you can use in jQuery to select different combinations of elements. It overlaps mostly with what you can use in CSS, plus a few extra jQuery-specific ones.

Answer (score 1):

Change the selector from selecting all inputs to just the one you want e.g. `$('#a').on('input', ...`